# Move files to parent directory of current location

Tags: linux, shell, mv

I have a lot of folders that have a folder inside them, with files inside. I want to move the 2nd level files into the 1st level and do so without knowing their names.

Simple example:

- Before running a script:

  ```
  /temp/1stlevel/test.txt
  /temp/1stlevel/2ndlevel/test.rtf
  ```
- After running a script:

  ```
  /temp/1stlevel/test.txt
  /temp/1stlevel/test.rtf
  ```

I'm getting very close but I'm missing something and I'm sure it's simple/stupid. Here's what I'm running:

```
find . -mindepth 3 -type f -exec sh -c 'mv -i "$1" "${1%/*}"' sh {} \;
```

Here's what that's getting me:

```
mv: './1stlevel/2ndlevel/test.rtf' and './1stlevel/2ndlevel/test.rtf' are the same file
```

Any suggestions?

UPDATE: George, this is great stuff, thank you! I'm learning a lot and taking notes. Using the `mv` command instead of the more complicated one is brilliant. Far from the first time I've been accused of doing something the hardest way possible!

However, while it works great with 1 set of folders, if I have more, it doesn't work as intended. Here's what I mean:

Before:

```
new
└── temp
    ├── Folder1
    │   ├── SubFolder1
    │   │   └── SubTest1.txt
    │   └── Test1.txt
    ├── Folder2
    │   ├── SubFolder2
    │   │   └── SubTest2.txt
    │   └── Test2.txt
    └── Folder3
        ├── SubFolder3
        │   └── SubTest3.txt
        └── Test3.txt
```

After:

```
new
└── temp
    └── Folder3
        ├── Folder1
        │   ├── SubFolder1
        │   └── Test1.txt
        ├── Folder2
        │   ├── SubFolder2
        │   └── Test2.txt
        ├── SubFolder3
        ├── SubTest1.txt
        ├── SubTest2.txt
        ├── SubTest3.txt
        └── Test3.txt
```

Desired:

```
new
└── temp
    ├── Folder1
    │   ├── SubFolder1
    │   ├── SubTest1.txt
    │   └── Test1.txt
    ├── Folder2
    │   ├── SubFolder2
    │   ├── SubTest2.txt
    │   └── Test2.txt
    └── Folder3
        ├── SubFolder3
        ├── SubTest3.txt
        └── Test3.txt
```

If one wanted to get fancy*:

```
new
└── temp
    ├── Folder1
    │   ├── SubTest1.txt
    │   └── Test1.txt
    ├── Folder2
    │   ├── SubTest2.txt
    │   └── Test2.txt
    └── Folder3
        ├── SubTest3.txt
        └── Test3.txt
```

- I don't need to get fancy, though, 'cause later in my script I just remove empty folders.

BTW, that took me forever in Notepad++ to draw. What did you use?

Comment: Indeed you got my attention with the question's title  :)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Duly noted, jww, thank you. I'll leave it here since George is being very helpful, but I've added it to Super User [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1316293/linux-move-files-from-unknown-folder-to-unknown-parent-of-the-same-unknown-fold).

Comment: Well, jww, it's been downvoted there and the only comment is someone complaining about crossposting. Now you see why I chose here instead, People such as George seem to be more helpful here.

Comment: @jww. This is a very clearly posed question with a solid amount of effort presented. The only possible reason you could have for claiming it is off topic is that OP chose bash as their scripting language of choice. Would you have voted to close the same question but about Python?

Comment: @Peter. Take a look at the `tree` command. Also, the trick behind the plain `mv` command is called globbing (the shell expanding wildcards).

Comment: @MadPhysicist - The bar is a little higher than tacking "... in a script" onto a question. Assuming [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/) still holds, it is just a question on how to run the `find` and `mv` commands.

Comment: @jww. I disagree. It's very clearly a question about how to move files around in a very particular, clearly described, fashion. Clearly `mv` will figure into it at some point if you're using bash, and `find` happened to be part of OP's attempt. But as the posted answer shows, it can be done using without `find`, using a feature of the bash programming language. This is definitely a programming question, and would be even if it wasn't happening in a script at all.

Comment: @Peter your script is ready, please test it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me use this example to illustrate:

Tree structure:

```
new
└── temp
    └── 1stlevel
        ├── 2ndlevel
        │   └── text.rtf
        └── test.txt
```

Move with:

```
find . -mindepth 4 -type f -exec mv {} ./*/* \;
```

Result after move:

```
new
└── temp
    └── 1stlevel
        ├── 2ndlevel
        ├── test.txt
        └── text.rtf
```

Where you run it from matters, I am running from one folder up from the `temp` folder, if you want to run it from the `temp` folder then the command would be:

```
find 1stlevel/ -mindepth 2 -type f -exec mv {} ./* \;
```

Or:

```
find ./ -mindepth 3 -type f -exec mv {} ./* \;
```

Please look closely at the section `find ./ -mindepth 3`, remember that `-mindepth 1 means process all files except the starting-points`. So if you start from `temp` and are after a file in `temp/1st/2nd/` then you will access it with `-mindepth 3` starting at temp. Please see: `man find`.

Now for the destination I used `./*/*`, interpretation "from current (one up from temp, mine was new) directory down to `temp`, then `1stlevel`, so:

- `./`: => new folder
- `./*`: => new/temp folder
- `./*/*`: => new/temp/1stlevel

But all that is for the `find` command but another trick is to use the `mv` command only from the `new` folder:

```
mv ./*/*/*/* ./*/*
```

This is run from the new folder in my example (in other words from one folder up the temp folder). Make adjustments to run it at different levels.

To run from the `temp` folder:

```
mv ./*/*/* ./*
```

If your bordered about time since you mentioned you had a lot of files, then the `mv` option beats the `find` option. See the time results for just three files:

find:

```
real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

mv:

```
real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

#### Update:

Since OP wants a script to access multiple folders I came with this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for i in ./*/*/*;
do
        if [[ -d "$i" ]];
        then
                # Move the files to the new location
                mv "$i"/* "${i%/*}/"
                # Remove the empty directories
                rm -rf "$i"

        fi
done
```

#### How to: Run from the new folder: `./move.sh`, remember to make the script executable with `chmod +x move.sh`.

Target directory structure:

```
new
├── move.sh
└── temp
    ├── folder1
    │   ├── subfolder1
    │   │   └── subtext1.txt
    │   └── test1.txt
    ├── folder2
    │   ├── subfolder2
    │   │   └── subtext2.txt
    │   └── test1.txt
    └── folder3
        ├── subfolder3
        │   └── subtext3.txt
        └── test1.txt
```

Get fancy result:

```
new
├── move.sh
└── temp
    ├── folder1
    │   ├── subtext1.txt
    │   └── text1.txt
    ├── folder2
    │   ├── subtext2.txt
    │   └── text2.txt
    └── folder3
        ├── subtext3.txt
        └── text3.txt
```

Comment: Ok, fifth time is the charm! My apologies for all of the add/removing of comments. The system isn't playing nice with me! LOL. I've edited my post with my reply. Thanks!

Comment: Aplogies for the delay, work got in the way of personal. George, this is absolutely perfect! Works exactly the way I wanted it to do. Thank you so much for coming back and updating the answer!

Answer (score 4):

Your `find . -mindepth 3 -type f -exec sh -c 'mv -i "$1" "${1%/*}"' sh {} \;`
attempt is very close to being right. 
A useful technique when debugging complex commands
is to insert `echo` statements to see what is happening. 
So, if we say

```
$ find . -mindepth 3 -type f -exec sh -c 'echo mv -i "$1" "${1%/*}"' sh {} \;
```

we get

```
mv -i ./Folder1/SubFolder1/SubTest1.txt ./Folder1/SubFolder1
mv -i ./Folder2/SubFolder2/SubTest2.txt ./Folder2/SubFolder2
mv -i ./Folder3/SubFolder3/SubTest3.txt ./Folder3/SubFolder3
```

which makes perfect sense — it’s finding all the files at depth 3 (and beyond),
stripping the last level off the pathname, and moving the file there. 
But,

```
mv  (path_to_file)  (path_to_directory)
```

means
move the file into the directory.
So the command `mv -i ./Folder1/SubFolder1/SubTest1.txt ./Folder1/SubFolder1`
means move `Folder1/SubFolder1/SubTest1.txt` *into* `Folder1/SubFolder1` —
but that’s where it already is. 
Therefore, you got error messages saying
that you were moving a file to where it already was.

As is clear from your illustration,
you want to move `SubTest1.txt` into `Folder1`. 
One quick fix is

```
$ find . -mindepth 3 -type f -exec sh -c 'mv -i "$1" "${1%/*}/.."' sh {} \;
```

which uses `..` to go up from `SubFolder1` to `Folder1`:

```
mv -i ./Folder1/SubFolder1/SubTest1.txt ./Folder1/SubFolder1/..
mv -i ./Folder2/SubFolder2/SubTest2.txt ./Folder2/SubFolder2/..
mv -i ./Folder3/SubFolder3/SubTest3.txt ./Folder3/SubFolder3/..
```

I believe that that’s bad style, although I can’t figure out quite why. 
I would prefer

```
$ find . -mindepth 3 -type f -exec sh -c 'mv -i "$1" "${1%/*/*}"' sh {} \;
```

which uses `%/*/*` to remove two components from the pathname of the file
to get what you really want,

```
mv -i ./Folder1/SubFolder1/SubTest1.txt ./Folder1
mv -i ./Folder2/SubFolder2/SubTest2.txt ./Folder2
mv -i ./Folder3/SubFolder3/SubTest3.txt ./Folder3
```

You can then use

```
$ find . -mindepth 2 -type d –delete
```

to delete the empty `SubFolderN` directories. 
If, through some malfunction, any of them is not empty,
`find` will leave it alone and issue a warning message.

Comment: This is what I would do, but I would place a '/' at the end of the target directory, "${1%/*/*}"/ to clearly show that the target is a directory. Not necessary however.

Comment: Thank you, G-Man! I'm going to use your trick with the echo statement quite a bit. That'll help me puzzle more things out on my own before I have to ask for help, which is what I prefer.

Answer (score 0):

```
mv YOUR-FILE-NAME ../
```

Ii thould work this way if u have writing permissions

Answer (score 0):

Have your script navigate to each directory where you need the files moved "up," then you can have `find` find each file in the directory, then move them up one directory:

```
 $ find . -type f -exec mv {} ../. \;
```

Comment: (1) This will move *every* file — including `Test1.txt`, `Test2.txt`, and `Test3.txt`, which are not supposed to be moved at all — into `new`  (i.e., the parent of `temp`).  (2) Why do you say `../.` instead of `..`?